# Method to not parse the whole table for an SQL Query in Java - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, query-optimization

Let's say we have a **very large** table, and we have queries in the form of (this is an example only)

```
SELECT personID FROM people WHERE birthYear>2010 LIMIT 50
```

I want to maximize the performance of getting the results of that query, the problem is that the database will parse the whole table to find the tuples that match the condition and then return the first 50. That is a problem if we have a database with millions or billions of tuples.

Is there a way in Java - JDBC or SQL to not parse the whole table and either parse it progressively and get the first 50 that match the condition, or parse the first 1000 rows for example and get all of them that match, and keep fetching more results when the user clicks a "Show More" button?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: DO you have index on birthYear column? You limit 50 records but by what order? You always need to have a order by clause with a LIMIT otherwise mysql returns 50 records randomly

Comment: The query was just an example. It won't be always WHERE birthYear etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not real.  Here's an analysis of what might happen:

```
SELECT personID FROM people WHERE birthYear>1900 LIMIT 50
SELECT personID FROM people WHERE birthYear>2010 LIMIT 50
```

Case 1:  No index on birthYear:

- 1900:  It will scan the table *only until 50 rows match the `WHERE` clause*.  This is likely to be the first 50.
- 2010:  It will scan most or all of the table unless it is a catalog of young kids.  So, it might need to read all the rows to find 50.

Case 2:  An index *starting with* birthYear:

It will jump into the middle of the index to the first value with >1900 (or >2010), then grab the next 50 rows (or fewer).  For each of those rows, it will reach into the table for `personID`.

Case 3:  `INDEX(birthYear, personID)`:

As with case 2, but it does not need to "reach into the table".  This is because `personID` is part of the index.

Only in case 1, and only if fewer than 50 rows have >1900 (seems unlikely), will it scan the entire table.  Cases 2 and 3 stop promptly at 50.

Comment: Is it true? When I do that, the size of the query's result is the total number of rows, that's why I thought it scans the entire table. No?

Comment: @PavTze - Do you have anyone who was born before 1900?  I don't think there is any one alive that is that old.

Comment: Phrased another way,...  The Optimizer uses whatever is available to minimize the work to perform -- index, WHERE, LIMIT, etc.

Comment: The query was an example, it can be with any values needed, not 1900. So what I am asking regarding the Case 1 is whether for ANY query with the LIMIT, it will parse the table until 50 rows match the where clause, or not?

Comment: @PavTze - I expect the result set to have no more than 50 rows, due to the `LIMIT 50`.  _The values matter!_  I answered your question based on `1900`.  If it is reaily 2015, a lot of things change!

Comment: `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 50` _may_ have to read the entire table, sort it, then deliver only 50.  Ditto for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I edited my question regarding the value. Can you update your answer please?

Comment: @PavTze - I changed my Answer.  Case 1 may involve a table scan.

Comment: Thanks! So the solution has to take place in the database (through indexes for example), and there is no possible solution on the client, correct? Including SQL Query rewriting.

Comment: @PavTze - Fetching an entire table into the client rarely makes sense.  And, once you understand the power of SQL, doing things in SQL often takes less coding.  (Consider:  adding a WHERE or GROUP BY versus building a client loop to extract the desired data.)

Comment: I see. What I am asking if whether we can predict a full table scan, and whether there is an alternative to that coding wise or SQL Query rewriting wise? I'm building an app where I don't write the SQL Queries by myself, the users write them and I am trying to optimize the process for fetching the results without having to fetch and parse the whole table. So I have the option to rewrite an SQL Query, but not write it from the start.

Comment: @PavTze - If the end-user is allowed to create queries, there _will be_ table scans; it is much to complex to try to prevent such.  On the other hand, if you provide an API, you can control what "questions" a use asks, then you can (mostly) prevent "slow" queries.  But it means being willing to go in and add an index when a user demands a new feature.  And there will still be tough queries that defy optimization.  (Look at all the queries on this forum that ask for "optimization" or "faster" or "performance".)

Answer (score 0):

Two things you have to do in this case-

1. Create an index of birthYear and personID
2. Do the partitioning on the table on year wise